# Android Constraint Layout Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

In iOS I'm a big fan of deleting the storyboard and using the Cartography framework to lay everything out in code. This is stolen from Cartography's github:

```
constrain(view1, view2) { view1, view2 in
    view1.width   == (view1.superview!.width - 50) * 0.5
    view2.width   == view1.width - 50
    view1.height  == 40
    view2.height  == view1.height
    view1.centerX == view1.superview!.centerX
    view2.centerX == view1.centerX

    view1.top >= view1.superview!.top + 20
    view2.top == view1.bottom + 20
}
```

Is there any equivalent at all for Android? It seems like the new Constraint Layout is a step in the right direction but I would like to do it programmatically.

Comment: there are so many reasons why people want to do this programmatically, for example, people are developing libraries other than apps that has a pre-defined ui, or people need to change layout specifications affected by user interactions at runtime and even more reasons... Google is really lacking docs on this new feature

Comment: Another (simple) reason, @Polarbear0106 is that if you need to use the TransitionManager and particularly `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root);` then you _need_ to specify your layout changes manually so they get rendered in the next pass. So, yes, there are times when you need to modify stuff programmatically.

Answer (score 74):

A little late to the game, but you need to basically treat your views in a constraint layout as regular views that simply have their own LayoutParams.

In the ConstraintLayout case, the documentation is located here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams

> This class contains the different attributes specifying how a view want to be laid out inside a ConstraintLayout. For building up constraints at run time, using ConstraintSet is recommended.

So, the recommended method is to use a [ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet).

There's a nice code sample there, but the core concept is you need to create a new set (by copying/cloning/new, etc), set its properties, and then apply it to your layout.

E.g.: Suppose your layout contains a ConstraintLayout (called mConstraintLayout here) and inside it contains a view (R.id.go_button in the sample), you could do:

```
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    // You may want (optional) to start with the existing constraint,
    // so uncomment this.
    // set.clone(mConstraintLayout); 

    // Resize to 100dp
    set.constrainHeight(R.id.go_button, (int)(100 * density));
    set.constrainWidth(R.id.go_button, (int)(100 * density));

    // center horizontally in the container
    set.centerHorizontally(R.id.go_button, R.id.rootLayout);

    // pin to the bottom of the container
    set.connect(R.id.go_button, BOTTOM, R.id.rootLayout, BOTTOM, 8);

    // Apply the changes
    set.applyTo(mConstraintLayout); 
    // this is my… (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
```

Comment: In my case, it was necessary to add

set.clone(mConstraintLayout)

to copy the current constraints before adding

Comment: Are you wearing a mop head @Martin Marconcini?

Comment: @TomHoward I wouldn’t dare! ;) (if you’re curious, http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/f0d0/) In case the link fails in the future, google “Dwarven Beard Hat” (I brought it @ think geek) like 5 yrs ago.

Comment: @CarlosPerezPerez thanks for the comment, I thought it was clear (in the text), but for extra-clarity, I’ve added the clone code (commented out) right there. +1 :)

Comment: The sentence ```For building up constraints at run time, using ConstraintSet is recommended.``` is confusing to me. The very fact that I am creating view programmatically means that I am defining constraints on run time. So I don't understand that line. I have a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030308/difference-between-constraintset-and-constraintlayout-layoutparams. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @MukeshGhatiya I left you a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the exact same dilemma coming from iOS where I feel like building views programatically is a more common practice.

I am actually porting the [Stevia](https://github.com/freshOS/Stevia) library to android with Kotlin [here](https://github.com/Yummypets/Stevia.kt), since the new ConstraintLayout is quite similar to our beloved Autolayout.

Here is how you define a simple view

```
class MyView(context: Context): ConstraintLayout(context) {

  val label = TextView(context)

  init {

      // View Hierarchy
      subviews(
          label
      )

      // Layout
      label.centerInParent()

      // Style
      label.style {
          textSize = 12F
      }
  }}
```

Be aware that this is Pure native Constraint layout under the hood, as explained by Martin's answer.

It's only the beginning but it has proven to be a delightful way to write android views in Kotlin so far so I thought I'd share.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am an user and contributer of Stevia on iOS. This is probably the best shot.