# Why isn't setLayoutParams changing the size of my ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, layoutparams

I have done this in the past and I am frustrated because this method is not working like I expect it to. I have an image that I want to resize to specific dimensions and I am using the code below:

```
snellen.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) snellen.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = (int)(converted*WIDTH_RATIO);
            params.height = (int)(converted*HEIGHT_RATIO);

            snellen.setLayoutParams(params);

            System.out.println("########################################################################### SNELLEN CHART WIDTH: : " + snellen.getWidth());
            System.out.println("########################################################################### SNELLEN CHART HEIGHT: : " + snellen.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

I have checked what both `(converted*WIDTH_RATIO)` and `(converted*HEIGHT_RATIO)` are and they are somewhere in the 100's. I have put it inside a handler so I can get the correct `getLayoutParams()` because I have had trouble with that in the past.

The problem is that when I print out what the width and hights are they are not what I have set them to inside the `params.width` and `params.height`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like it should work, doesn't it? Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40028802/6287910) for another way to approach this.

Comment: Since `snellen`'s parent appears to be a `ConstraintLayout`, is it possible that the constraints are so specific they're not allowing you to control the view's size?

Comment: @BenP. You were right. I had to set my image to just be constrained to one side of the screen instead of being constrained on all sides using my guidelines I created. Then it was able to resize the image. Just wow, I never expected that to be a problem. Feel free to post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're casting `snellen`'s `LayoutParams` to `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`, it seems likely that your view is the child of a `ConstraintLayout`.

If that is the case, it is possible that the problem is that your view's dimensions are defined by its set of constraints, and so changing `params.width` and `params.height` will have no effect.

Check your view's constraints and make sure they are not determining the view's dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `snellen.requestLayout()` I hope that help you

Comment: where? above my .post or above my call to getLayoutParams?

Comment: after snellen.setLayoutParams(params);
but what i checked that values which you try to assigned is not assigned to Imageview

Comment: Yeah just tried adding it and it didn't seem to do anything. Thanks anyways

Comment: what is the parent layout for imageview /

Comment: a constraintLayout

Comment: i tried your code sample with static values it's working fine , i think problem with your (converted*WIDTH_RATIO) and (converted*HEIGHT_RATIO)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150871/discussion-between-cjnash-and-ahmed-aboelyazeed).