# Programmatically change height in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple layout: a fixed height TextView with three ImageView objects anchored to the bottom of the view.

[image]

How can I programmatically change the height of each of the ImageViews so they vary within some range (10dp, 16dp below the TextView)? Concretely, my activity gets a list of percentages (between 0 and 1) representing how much of that vertical space each of those "bars" should take up.

I've tried the following without success:

```
// No visible difference
imgView.setMinHeight(newHeight);

// No change to height, but horizontal constrained was messed up
imgView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParam(imgView.getWidth(), newHeight);
```

Comment: You would get the ConstraintSet from the elements you want to change, and tweak them. Refer to this answer for a how-to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40028802/4232337

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If by "height" you mean the absolute top-to-bottom dimension of the `ImageView`, you can do the following to double the height of an `ImageView`. You can set the height to the value that you want.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) iv.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = lp.height * 2;
iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

See [ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.html).

But, if by "height" you mean the vertical position of the `ImageView`, you can do the following to change the `ImageView`'s vertical bias (assuming that you are using `ConstraintLaytout`):

```
ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
cs.clone(layout);
cs.setVerticalBias(R.id.imageView, 0.25f);
cs.applyTo(layout);
```

See [setVerticalBias](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#setVerticalBias(int,%20float)).

There are other ways to move an `ImageView` about the layout, but which you use would depend on how your layout is set up.